# Change default font style in Visual Studio markdown preview

Tags: configuration, fonts, markdown, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

There's no configuration option in Web Essentials for VS2013 addin to set font style of markdown preview display. Is it possible to configure it using other means i.e. changing files?

I would like to either change it to some more readable serif font or change it to sans serif...

Comment: It doesn't appear to be in the 2013 version yet judging from the change logs http://vswebessentials.com/changelog. Here is says it is possible to add a custome stylesheet http://vswebessentials.com/features/markdown but i haven't found how yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. For some reason the context menu for "create markdown stylesheet" is disabled in 2013 but if you add the file yourself it works. In the solution root make a folder "Solution Items" and a file "WE-Markdown.css"

you should be able to add styles now and it will updates in your markdown preview.

NOTE: i was using version 1.6 Web Essentials for VS2013

EDIT:

As a simple example i am just using a bootstrap cdn include

```
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

Though it seems that the css support is not very advanced and there are some issues with multi line code blocks. there may be a way to fix this with some css overrides

Comment: [Here's an example](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2014/01/web-essentials-markdown-preview-default.html) of such stylesheet file that anyone can use in their solution.